# Clase abstracta controller en proyectos Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

Estoy haciendo una clase abstracta para el controller de un proyecto Spring usando MVC,
pero al intentar hacerla me estoy encontrando con varios problemas que no logro solucionar:

```
@RestController
public abstract class Controller<T, K, R extends JpaRepository<T, K>> {

    protected final String TABLE_NAME = "";
    
    @Autowired
    Service<T, K, R> service;

    @GetMapping({ "/", "/" + TABLE_NAME })
    public List<T> getAll() {
        return service.findAll();
    }

    @PutMapping("/" + TABLE_NAME + "/{id}")
    public void updateEntity(@PathVariable("id") K id, T entity) {
        service.save(entity);
    }

    @PostMapping("/" + TABLE_NAME)
    public void createEntity(@RequestBody T entity) {
        service.save(entity);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/" + TABLE_NAME + "/{id}")
    public void deleteEntity(@PathVariable("id") K id) {
        service.delete(id);
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
public class AlumnoController extends Controller<Alumno, String, AlumnoRepository>{
    
}
```

Quiero poder asignar desde `AlumnoController` el nombre de la tabla que va a recibir el controller, pero al hacerlo me salta un error de que no puedo modificar un campo final (lógicamente), el problema llega cuando quito el final, en ese momento me aparece que no puedo usar variables, tengo que usar constantes, así que estoy en un bucle y no se como continuar.

Error:
`The value for annotation attribute PutMapping.value must be a constant expression`
(PutMapping por ejemplo, el error aparece en todos los métodos)

El objetivo es que la clase `AlumnoController` esté vacía o como mucho especificando el nombre de la tabla, para no tocar la clase abstracta en ningún momento.

Mi segundo problema es que no consigo quitar la anotación `@RestController` de la clase `AlumnoController`, No se si es porque me falta algo o Spring no hereda anotaciones entre clases.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por partes:

- La anotación de Spring `@RestController` **no** se hereda, ya que , a su vez no tiene la anotación `@Inherited`. Lo mismo ocurre con `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping`, etc.
- Las anotaciones requieren que las rutas sean valores constantes conocidos en tiempo de compilación, no podrás usar `TABLE` para definir las rutas a menos que su valor sea `final static`.
- Estás acoplando el código de la capa web (los controllers) con la capa de persistencia. Un cambio en la capa de persistencia te obligaría a hacer cambios en el controlador.
- Los genéricos desaparecen en tiempo de ejecución, por lo que todos tus servicios serían del mismo tipo (`Service`), lo que te complicaría la inyección de dependencias (tendrías que usar anotaciones extras para dar identificadores a los `@Service` si quieres que Spring no se queje de la ambigüedad.
- Es imposible añadir validaciones a los valores que recibes si no los escribes/anotas para cada recurso (*endpoint*) expuesto.

Mi opinión:

Si lo piensas bien, algo tan genérico y que ahorra tanto código como lo que intentas hacer sería ya parte de Spring Framework si fuera posible implementarlo.

Por último, esta estrategia va frontalmente en contra del código limpio y de los principios del DDD (Diseño Dirigido por el Dominio, *Domain Driven Development*) y la arquitectura hexagonal.

Comment: Ya veo, osea que no se puede hacer, logré hacer una clase abstracta con la clase de Service así que pensé que quizás con el Controller podría lograr hacerlo, de todas formas, si intento añadir mi propia anotación que registre el tableName que quiero, eso podría funcionar? Al fin y al cabo Spring se basa en anotaciones principalmente no?